# Alloy : pre-order traversal of binary tree in required ordering

Tags: data-structures, binary-tree, alloy

I want a "pre-order" traversal of the nodes in BinaryTree visits them in 
this order [N0,N1,N2,N3]
What should I do with the following structure?

```
one sig Ordering { // model a linear order on nodes 
  first: Node, // the first node in the linear order 
  order: Node -> Node // for each node n, n.(Ordering.order) represents the
                      // node (if any) immediately after n in order 
}
fact LinearOrder { // the first node in the linear order is N0; and 
                   // the four nodes are ordered as [N0, N1, N2, N3]
}
pred SymmetryBreaking(t: BinaryTree) { // if t has a root node, it is the
   //first node according to the linear order; and 
   // a "pre-order" traversal of the nodes in t visits them according 
   //to the linear order
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question has 2 part. First, define ordering for N0, N1.......  Second, define symmetry break using  Linear ordering.

First, you can define ordering by list all the valid relationship, like

```
`N0.(Ordering.order) = N1`
```

Second, define the predicate that pre-order of tree follow linear ordering. Basically, there are 2 cases, and the first one is trivial , no t.root . However when the root is not NULL, the tree must has following 3 property.

1. For all node n, if h = n.left, h.val = n.val.(Ordering.order)
2. For all node n, if h = n.right, h.val = (one node in n's left-sub-tree or   n).(Ordering.order)
3. t.root = N0

If you translate the whole description into alloy, it will be something like

`no t.root or

    { 
        t.root = N0  // 3
        all h : t.root.^(left+right) | one n : t.root.*(left+right) | 
        (n.left = h and n.(Ordering.order) = h ) or //1
        ( one l :( n.left*(left+right) + n)| n.right = h and l.(Ordering.order) = h)//2

    }`

Note : there may be many alternative solution, and this one is definitely not a simple one.